# 406 Error on jquery AJAX request

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post, http-status-code-406

This is driving me mad. I'm getting a 406 error when I make an AJAX request at my hosting (Linux), but not on my local machine (Windows 7). Both using Apache. All other requests that have the same format, e.g.

```
http://cms.hogsmill.com/Lib/actionCMS.php?Action=saveContentText&SectionId=155&Text=...
```

where ... is the text I'm sending - all work fine. The text is Javascript encodeURI'ed before sending. The text that breaks is the following; seems to be something wrong with the "by default all users..." paragraph.

Any ideas?

---

To create a new page, click on 'New Page'. To edit an existing page click the edit page icon. In both cases, the editor on the left will popup.

Type in the name of the page in the 'Label' field. The URL for the page will be automatically populated. Only edit the URL if it doesn't look sensible. You can only change the URL for a new page; if you need to change an existing URL, contact Hogsmill.

By default, all pages are accessible by everybody. To limit access just to logged in users, unclick 'All' and select a different user type.

Typically there are two types of users:

- **Site Admin** - able to edit content, and see all logged in only pages.
- **User** - cannot edit content, but can see all logged in only pages.

Answer (score 2):

Probably, the best, it's to analyze the HTTP headers of Your client request. It should contain some "Accept" headers, which conflicts with server response, as I understood the nature of this anomaly.

[Details for 406 status code](http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E406.html)

Answer (score 0):

this recently happened to me, using Chrome, headers viewed through Chrome's developer tools seemed to indicate everything was fine, then the next test, it worked without an error. so I have no idea what "fixed" it.